# Unable to execute command in `Alt' + `F2'

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, tor

I want to set a shortcut for my tor browser. My tor folder is in my $HOME directory. In order to execute it, I should run: `start-tor-browser` when I'm in `~/tor-browser-linux64-8.5.3_en-US/tor-browser_en-US/Browser`.

I added the directory to my **~/.bashrc** and ran `source ~/.bashrc`. Now,I can run `start-tor-browser` from everywhere in my terminal, but it doesn't work in my <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> box. Besides when I set a shortcut, using the `start-tor-browser` command, it doesn't work. I'd like to know:

- Why does it work in terminal and not in <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>?
- How can I solve this problem and set a shortcut?

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>  +  <kbd>F2</kbd>  does not use the `bash` shell (`$`), it uses the GNOME shell or the shell used by the desktop environment (for example:- GNOME and XFCE). You can only run the desktop's shell commands in it (for eg:- running `r` in the GNOME shell will restart the shell, whereas running `r` in a terminal window will not do anything).

Alias added to `~/.bashrc` will only work in `$` bash shell terminals. GNOME shell or any desktop's shell does not support bash commands.

You cannot run shell commands or aliases in the GNOME shell ( <kbd>Alt</kbd>  +  <kbd>F2</kbd> ) or another shell other than bash. If the application is installed then running its package name will launch the application. (For example:- Running `firefox` will launch the Firefox application).

**You can define your commands in `~/.profile` instead**. GNOME and XFCE definitely reads and understand the commands defined in `~/.profile`.

See [Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ChangingShells#:%7E:text=A%20shell%20is%20a%20program,for%20Unix%2Dlike%20operating%20systems.&text=For%20example%2C%20the%20csh%20shell,is%20sometimes%20preferred%20by%20programmers.).